# How to add text on interactive Scatter on Altair?

Tags: text, interactive, altair

I try to adapt the *Selection Detail Example* from altair doc (https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/select_detail.html#selection-detail-example).

I won't detailed my Dataframe structure which is identical with the one from the example (included variable names).

The native code is working well :

```
# Data is prepared, now make a chart

selector = alt.selection_single(empty='all', fields=['id'])

base = alt.Chart(data).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
).add_selection(selector)


points = base.mark_point(filled=True, size=200,opacity=0.9).encode(
    x=alt.X('mean(y)',title='Durée de perception',scale=alt.Scale(domain=(11, 23))),
    y=alt.Y('mean(x)',title='Taux de marge (%PM)'),
    color=alt.condition(selector, 'id:O', alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip = ['mean(y)','mean(x)']
)

timeseries = base.mark_bar(opacity=1).encode(
    x=alt.X('time', title='Items'),
    y=alt.Y('value', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-1, 1)),stack=None),
    color=alt.Color('id:O',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_))
                    #, legend=None)
).transform_filter(
    selector
)

points | timeseries
```

[image]

No problem at this stage even if **it could be useful to hide all the bars on right chart when no selection is made** on the right chart (don't know if it's possible ?)

After that I try to add text to the scatter plot adding this at the end of the code :

```
text = points.mark_text(dy=-5).encode(
    x=alt.X('mean(y)',title='Durée de perception',scale=alt.Scale(domain=(11, 23))),
    y=alt.Y('mean(x)',title='NBV (%CA)'),
    text='id:O'
)


(points + text) | timeseries
```

which leads to the following error message :

*Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector094_tuple"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.*

If you have any idea on how to do, i would be grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot add the same selection to two different layers, which you do implicitly by deriving `text` from `points`. Try this instead:

```python
text = alt.Chart(data).mark_text(dy=-5).encode(
    x=alt.X('mean(y)',title='Durée de perception',scale=alt.Scale(domain=(11, 23))),
    y=alt.Y('mean(x)',title='NBV (%CA)'),
    text='id:O'
)


(points + text) | timeseries
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I better understand and it works fine.